Dockerhub Pimcore image
I would like to use/extend the pimcore dockerhub image (as I need to customize certain things).
The image layers are here:
https://registry.hub.docker.com/layers/pimcore/pimcore/php8.1-debug-latest/images/sha256-c2bba6e4dcc40ef8554778d139f986fe1cef2393410fb79e9ea7d9da6916a04d?context=explore
The first layer's command is:

What is this file (can I see what it contains anywhere)? Where does it come from?
Also, how come there are multiple CMD statements (from docs it says only one allowed, if multiple only last will be run, so why have multiple?):

Sorry if this is a silly question, relatively new dockerhub/docker user. Not expecting full explanation, just a link which might explain how this works would be helpful (I've searched but not coming up with much so far, not entirely sure what to search for)

The ADD <hash> syntax is opaque; without getting the original source repository you can't see what's in it.  You're right that only the last CMD has an effect, but if base images provided their own CMD, they'll still be recorded in the history.

Docker images can extend each other.
The image you linked to, pimcore/pimcore extends a variant of php-fpm which extends debian-bookworm. It's not until layer 33 (in the link) that the pimcore/pimcore Dockerfile does anything. All layers above are from upstream projects.

What is this file (can I see what it contains anywhere)? Where does it come from?

This file is very likely to be the image's root file system which in this case is a rather bare Debian installation. "A .zip of a fresh install of Debian" in not-quite-correct terms.

Also, how come there are multiple CMD statements

It's better for that image to set its own CMD so it's sure what value it contains than hope that php-fpm doesn't ever change it to something else. Functionally, right now it makes no difference.
Only the very latest CMD value is used, so other entries are ignored.

Thanks @RickN, appreciate the explanation. I understand that images can extend each other, but doesn't that require a 'FROM {parentImage}' ?
"The image you linked to, pimcore/pimcore extends a variant of php-fpm" - how if I may ask can you tell this exactly (without a 'FROM' statement)?

It's because you're looking at the (flattened) layers, not the Dockerfile. If you go to the repository (linked on Docker Hub) & the Dockerfile there, you'll see FROM pimcore_php_default AS pimcore_php_debug, FROM pimcore_php_min AS pimcore_php_default, FROM php:${PHP_VERSION}-fpm-${DEBIAN_VERSION} AS pimcore_php_min and so on. The PHP Dockerfile extends Debian, etc.

The flattened layers are super cryptic, the link to the github certainly helps. Thanks @RickN
